# How do I prevent direct access to documents in GlassFish?

Tags: .htaccess, security, coldfusion, glassfish

I have a directory on my site with PDF files, each file is named using the ID of it's record (i.e. 12345.pdf, 67891.pdf).

I want to prevent a user from access PDF files directly by simply typing in the URL of a file. I want to force the user to use a page script to access the file (e.g. /getFile?12345, where the getFile script would retrieve the file and display).

I know using Apache you can modify the htaccess file to restrict direct access for certain file types, but I'm using GlassFish 3.1.2 and, being relatively new to it, I can't find anything about accomplishing something similar. Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: There are likely a few ways to accomplish this, the one that seems the most robust would be to have the PDF files located in a directory not being served by your web server, but still accessible to the ColdFusion server so it could fetch them on demand, for authorized users, and deliver them. I'm not familiar with GlassFish, but on IIS or Apache, I would place these files in a sub-directory above the web root, thereby making them not directly accessible through the web server.

Comment: @AveryMartell is on the mark. Here's a quick example from Ray Camden: http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2006/3/10/Ask-a-Jedi-Using-ColdFusion-to-serve-files EDIT: This is a CODING ISSUE on top of where to store the files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with exact issue right now and I have a solution that works (for me).

Step one confirm which you are using GlassFish on Apache or GlassFish on IIS.

Here is what worked for me.  I have IIS redirect access to the directory that the files are in using web.config. There is a redirect on the directory and the files within:

```
<rule name="Protect files and directories from prying eyes" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(myPDFDirectory)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
    <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" subStatusCode="0" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="Access is forbidden." />
</rule>
```

Or you can redirect them to your custom user capture stuff.

In htaccess it would be something like this (I am not good at Apache so you'll have to get a confirmation).

```
RewriteRule ^/myPDFDirectory/(.*)$ http://website.com/signUp.cfm [R=301,L]
```

I may have to review the first of the two examples but you get the point.

Now on to the file delivery.

I have seen this done the header content method. But unfortunately there is something going on with the server and it cannot access the directory with the PDF files. So I was able to access the files via HTTP.  With the rewrite rule in place there no access 'directly' to the directory of files for outside users navigating around, however, when I call the the PDF to download through a HREF it works.  I am using the new HTML 5 version of HREF with the download parameter. It forces download

```
<a href="/myPDFDirectory/realName.pdf" download="2014Expenses.pdf">Download Your Expense Report</a>
```

There are other ways to feed the user his or her files for download like the cfheader/cfcontent method but I don't have directory access set up properly and the servers are ones I don't admin so I had to come up with something unconventional :/

I hope this is helpful...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I'm not using IIS or Apache. I'm running glassfish off a unix server on the JVM. I think the best practice of storing documents outside of the web root is the ideal route.

Answer (score 0):

I followed Avery Martell's advice and looked outside the web root. I ended up setting up an NFS appliance to store the files and setup appropriate permissions. After some additional research, this is a common best practice, especially for my needs which is to store documents > 1MB. At that size the benefits of storing in a db start to diminish, and storing them in a directory within the web root is unnecessarily complicated. I hope this helps those with similar needs.